# Deutsche Bahn: I lost my BahnCard 25. Can I get some kind of proof of purchase to show to the ticket inspectors?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

Unfortunately, I lost my BahnCard 25 for 2017 (I still have the 2016 one, though). Can I get some kind of proof of purchase of the 2017 BahnCard in the ticket offices to show to the ticket inspector?

I know I should get a new one, but it's too late for that since I'll be needing the card next week and they take more time to make and send a new one, plus they don't answer my mails sent to bahncard-service@bahn.de and also it's a card which will expire next month, so it's probably not worth it to pay 15 euro for a replacement at this point.

So how can I produce a proof that my Bahncard is still valid while not having the actual card? Can I get such a document at the ticket offices in the stations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a smartphone with the DB navigator app, you can [load your BahnCard into the app as an electronic ticket](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/bahncard/bahncard-services/bahncard-handyticket.shtml). To do this you first need to activate BahnCard services via the website, using the PIN they send you when you get your BahnCard or by requesting a new one via email. Your BahnCard should then be available in the app under "BahnCard -> Meine BahnCards" in the menu. You may have to swipe down on the "Meine BahnCards" screen the first time you show it in order to load your card details into the app.

Answer (score 6):

You should call BahnCard-Service at +491806340035, which is available Mon-Fri: 7am - 9pm, Sat: 9am - 6pm. 20ct/call from landlines and max. 60ct/call from mobile lines.

Note that calling them directly is advised by Deutsche Bahn under your circumstances.

[Source](https://community.bahn.de/questions/1147291-bahncard-verloren-schnellstmoglich-neue-tun)